# Installation of DBI module in Perl facing issue

Tags: mysql, linux, perl

I have installed DBI module in Centos 7 server but whenever i am trying Connect to mysql through Perl script i am getting below ERROR as below please help on this

install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBD::mysql module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.24.1/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.24.1 .) at (eval 1195) line 3.
Perhaps the DBD::mysql perl module hasn't been fully installed,
or perhaps the capitalisation of 'mysql' isn't right.
Available drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Mem, Multiplex, Proxy, Sponge.
 at Registration.pl line 93.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `perl-DBD-MySQL`.

Edit: I read your error message and you are using a non-system perl in /usr/local (perl 5.24.1). If you are using that instead of the system perl, you can do:

```
cpan DBD::mysql DBI
```

You may need to also do:

```
yum  install mysql-devel
```

Comment: i all-ready  installed above thing still i am getting error and how to check DBI  is installed all packages correctly and if not how to remove DBI and  reinstall again so that i should not get above error

Comment: Ah, I see you are using a non-system perl. Editted the answer.

Comment: i installed mysql-devel and i tried to install DBD::mysql using ur command i am getting ERROR and also i tried with downloading tar file DBD and Followed step to install it, there i am getting ERROR as below

Comment: dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_dr_connect’:
dbdimp.c:2000:13: error: ‘MYSQL’ has no member named ‘reconnect’
       result->reconnect=0;
             ^

Comment: If tried execute the command give by you i.e cpan DBD::mysql DBI i am getting same error as above

Comment: most likely 5.24 is too new to run on your old version. I recommend you delete your perl in /usr/local and use the system version with system packages.

Comment: it not  perl local system ERROR actual i am running mariadb 10.2 which has a problem so we need to down load the Mariadb 10.2 patch i have patch but i dont know how to install it